# Advantages of using command line interface over GUI

Tags: linux, gui

I know its a simple question but what advantages does using a command line interface over GUI (graphical user interface) have?

Comment: Both interfaces have advantages and disadvantages. I would recommend looking at this website: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000619.htm